# What would happen if an object is created in non-static method of class in java?

Tags: java, instance, stack-overflow, heap-memory, local-variables

```
class Data {
    int x = 20; // instance variable

    public void show() // non-static method
    {
        Data d1 = new Data(); // object of same class Data
        int x = 10;
        System.out.println(x); // local x
        System.out.println(d1.x);// instance variable x
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Data d = new Data();
        d.show(); // "10 20"
    }
}
```

So my question when an object is created in show() namely 'd1' , it must have its own set of data members and must have allocated a new stack for its show() method , which in return should create a new object and thus the cycle should go on and stack-overflow occurs??
But this is working perfectly fine??

Comment: _must have allocated a new stack for its show()_ But you didn't invoke its `show` method. Why would it get executed?

Comment: Try calling `show()` in the constructor of your class and see **magic** happen

Comment: so, isn't it like memory is automatically allocated for methods()?

Comment: Even if memory is allocated, isn't that different than **invoking** a method? Do you think when you create an object all methods would be invoked by default while creation?

Comment: Okay , i think this cleared all my doubts!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Data d1=new Data();
```

this statement itself will not allocate a new stack for show(). show()'s stack is allocated only when it gets called, for example, when it gets called in main.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort

Answer (score 1):

Your `show()` method will be called only once. `show()` is NOT called when an instance of `Data` is being created. So, you will not get SOE.

Try this code to get SOE :P

```
class Data {
    int x = 20; // instance variable

    Data() {
        show(); // This will cause SOE
    }
    public void show() // non-static method
    {
        Data d1 = new Data(); // object of same class Data
        int x = 10;
        System.out.println(x); // local x
        System.out.println(d1.x);// instance variable x
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Data d = new Data();
        d.show(); // "10 20"
    }
}
```

Comment: just kidding buddy , but this really helped